# Using Ant Migration tool , No custom object deployed

Tags: ant, migration-tool, package.xml

I am using Ant migration tool to deploy some custom objects from one org ro another. Below is my package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Candidate__c</members>
        <members>Interview__c</members>
        <members>Interviewer__c</members>
        <members>Job_Application__c</members>
        <members>SFDC_Job_Opening__c</members>
        <members>Job_Opening_Skill__c</members>
        <members>Job_Opening_Skill_Profile__c</members>
    </types>
    <version>37.0</version>
</Package>
```

I used this link - [http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/migration-using-ant-in-salesforce/][1]

[1]: http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/migration-using-ant-in-salesforce/ for my reference to do the migration. I was able to retrieve the package with no errors and I get build successful without any errors. Also, I was able to deploy the package to the target org without any errors.

```
deployUnpackaged:
[sf:deploy] Request for a deploy submitted successfully.
[sf:deploy] Request ID for the current deploy task: 0Af360000131pmOCAQ
[sf:deploy] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Succeeded
[sf:deploy] *********** DEPLOYMENT SUCCEEDED ***********
[sf:deploy] Finished request 0Af360000131pmOCAQ successfully.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 5 seconds
```

But when I check my target org I don't see any of the custom object created. What could possibly have gone wrong?

Comment: you've missed <name>CustomObject</name>, between types and members

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed `<name>CustomObject</name>`, between types and members

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Candidate__c</members>
        <members>Interview__c</members>
        <members>Interviewer__c</members>
        <members>Job_Application__c</members>
        <members>SFDC_Job_Opening__c</members>
        <members>Job_Opening_Skill__c</members>
        <members>Job_Opening_Skill_Profile__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>37.0</version>
</Package>
```